# solving 1D equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, partial-derivative, fourier-transform

Is there any intelligent guy who could solve this equation for $p(k,t)$? $p(k,t)$ is the Fourier transport of $p(x,t)$ which is the probability of the particle to be at time $t$ at position $x$. $p(x,t)$ must be normalized in the interval $(0,l)$. $a$ is a constant and $i$ is used as the imaginary unit.

$p(k,t)+ \partial_t p(k,t)= -\frac{iak}{l}$

Comment: Could you please post the original equation, I think your transformed equation is wrong, in that the right side is probably missing a factor $p(k,t)$.

Comment: And probably the original transport equation was $∂_tp(x,t)=-a∂_xp(x,t)$, which would also ensure that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^l|p(x,t)|^2dx = -a\int_0^l\frac{d}{dx}|p(x,t)|^2dx=|p(l,t)|^2-|p(0,t)|^2=0$ under periodic boundary conditions. -- Or if normalized as a probability, $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^l p(x,t)\,dx = -a\int_0^l\frac{d}{dx} p(x,t)\,dx=p(l,t)-p(0,t)=0$.

Comment: The equation in the question is correct.

Comment: As $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}ke^{i2\pi\,k\,x/l}$ diverges everywhere (and is proportional to $\delta'(x)$ in a distributional sense) your equation does not make any sense. Also, as $\int_0^l p(x,t) dx\sim p(k=0,t)$, you get for the evolution of this integral $p(k=0,t)=p(k=0,0)·e^{-t}$, thus no preservation of normalization.

Answer (score 0):

$$p(k,t)+ \partial_t p(k,t)= -\frac{iak}{l}$$
Since there is only one derivative with respect to only one variable $
t$, the equation is a simple ODE. Solving it is straightforward :
$$p(k,t)=\frac{iak}{l}+C(k)e^{-t}$$
where $C(k)$ is any differentiable function of $k$.

Comment: but your solution is not normalized.

Comment: Could you tell me how o you want yo normalize p(x,t)?

Comment: above questions @JJacquelin